# SQLServer date condition in asp.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

in sql query if I got this condition :

```
Where (u.xdate BETWEEN N'" + startdate + "' AND N'" + enddate + "')
```

If I use :

```
startdate = 2014-04-20
enddate   = 2014-05-05

and the xdate 2014-05-01
```

what the result back ... ??? 
is sql server will consider that code is date ?

note : xdate is a nvarchar - startdate and enddate is a string

Comment: Sql server will do a explicit/implicit conversion.  It should work (but trying it would be the best hehe).http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx

Comment: If you don't have a DB to test the condition you can use [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: If `xdate` is a date, why is it stored as a varchar? You will be much better in the long run nipping this in the bud and altering your column. Databases with data stored in the [wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) are abhorrent. Once you have rectified that, start using [parameterised queries](http://bobby-tables.com/). It will allow for better query plan caching, it is more type safe, and will save you from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I have a database but I cannot test it because the data is add automatically  and I need to wait until day : 2014-05-05
to know how its work ... I tried to do CAST(u.xdate as DATE)
but its throw me an error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Finally, [Between is rarely the correct operator for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), and be careful using the format `2014-04-20`, this can still be interpreted as the 4th day of the 20th month and throw a conversion error (although not an issue when using strongly typed parameterised queries against a date/datetime column), the only culture invariant format for DateTime in SQL Server is `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: mmm I cannot change it now because the data is very sensitive

Comment: I add this to my code I guess it will solve the problem :

Where (CAST(u.xdate as DATE) BETWEEN CAST(N'" + startdate + "' as DATE) AND CAST(N'" + enddate + "' as DATE))

Comment: You can try this - 

**Where (CONVERT(Datetime, u.xdate, 120) BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "')**